# inserting new data into database, then displaying all the data doesnt show the new entry

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-activity

I created a database using SQLite in the MainActivity and added example data into it. The MainActivity is used to retrieve and show the data using a list and recyclerview

For inserting the example data, my code looks like this

```
// simplified version
db = new MyDBHandler(this);
rList = new ArrayList<>();
rList = db.GetRecipes();
if (rList.size() == 0) { CreateExampleRecipes(db); }
```

I went to a different activity, Activity2, to create a new data to be inserted into the database.

For the code, it looks like this

```
// simplified version
db = new MyDBHandler(this);
db.InsertData(String.valueOf(etRecipeName), Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(etDuration)), ingred, desc, steps);
finish();
```

The issue is, after using `finish();` in Activity2, the new data isnt displayed in the MainActivity.

**Edit 1**

Is there a way to share databases between activities? Or is sharing databases the only solution?

Comment: In general you should not create multiple instances of your SQL database helper, use a singleton. For your case, you probably need to refresh the data in the activity in onResume or otherwise notify it that the data changed. There are other ways of sharing data between activities though, like intents, shared preferences, or singletons

Comment: After successfully inserting the data you have to re-fetch the data from database.

Comment: @RakeshSaini how do I re-fetch the data? Do I implement an OnResume() method and tell the programme to re-look or re-read the data?

Comment: Create a method and write the fetching code inside that. Call that method again after successfully insert the data into database.